# Regex to replace &quot; with " only if it's not in another &quot;

Tags: c#, regex, xml

I'm converting [an encoded `XML` document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135657/set-xml-as-value-of-an-xml-node-attribute?answertab=active#tab-top) to its original format

```
string myXml = oldXml.Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&amp;", "&")
                                                   .Replace("&gt;", ">")
                                                   .Replace("&quot;", "\"")
                                                   .Replace("&apos;", "'");
```

It works fine. However I want to exclude `&quot;` if its in another `&quot;`.

Example:

*Original XML*

```
//Note the title value
<v:shape id="_x0000_i1025" title="a&quot; title &quot;b"> </v:shape>
```

*Encoded XML*

```
&lt;v:shape id=&quot;_x0000_i1025&quot; title=&quot;a&quot; title &quot;b&quot;&gt; &lt;/v:shape&gt;
```

*Recovered XML after replace*

```
//Note the title value
<v:shape id="_x0000_i1025" title="a" title "b"> </v:shape>
```

As you can see the inside `&quot;` shouldn't be convert to `"`. So how can I do the replace with Regex so that it doesn't replace the inside `&quot;`

Thank you

Comment: What encoded it to start with? I would fix the problem at source if you possibly can. (It would be fine if it had encoded `&` to `&amp;` - the fact that it's not doing that suggests the encoding part is horribly broken in general...)

Comment: @JonSkeet .Net does it automatically when I put  [an `xml` in another `xml` attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135657/set-xml-as-value-of-an-xml-node-attribute)

Comment: I'd expect it to do it properly then. Please provide a short but complete example of the cause.

Comment: Adding to @JonSkeet, the encoded XML should look like this: `title=&quot;a&amp;quot; title` (if it did, your decoder would work, although I'd go with an official implementation..)

Comment: @JonSkeet I get the encoded `xml` from an `xml attribute`, like the one I linked in the question, the replace special characters.

Comment: @Christian what do you mean by *an official implementation*?

Comment: @AlexJolig For example [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The only thing wrong with your xml is you are missing the namespace 'v'.

Comment: @AlexJolig:  Can you have the initial issue fixed? Encoded XML really should look like `title=&quot;a&amp;quot;`. If not, how can we tell where the attribute value boundary is? It is rather ambiguous then.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I don't need to recover the encoded `XML`.

Since `nodElement.SetAttribute("myXmlAttribute", myXml);` encodes the original Xml at the first place, when I read the attribute value and assign it to a string, `C#` will recover the original Xml automatically.

```
string content = theNode.Attributes["myXmlAttribute"].Value;
```

I don't need to do any replacing.